# Eclipse Plugin Development: Code Review

Tags: eclipse, plugins, analysis, review

I'm trying to write a plugin for Eclipse which should analyse all java files in the open project.

Is it possible to add my code to the code parser of Eclipse itself? 
Currently, I'm able to load the workspace and iterating over all java files but any changes after the first iteration are missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant` extension point to define a class extending `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CompilationParticipant` which will be called at various points during the compilation of a project.

You can also use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for changes to individual resources:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: The IResourcheChangeListener works great to get feedback once the files are saved but would it be possible to get 'live' feedback too? e.g., A listener which is executed once the user stops typing.

Comment: I don't use it but I think the compilation participant should be called during editing whenever the editor wants to update the code. The Java editor has a number of extension points described in the [Eclipse JDT Help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?nav=%2F3) but I don't think there is anything else to help.